# WordPress widget deleted

Tags: wordpress, widget

Does the following code mean that an **existing **widget on a WordPress page has been **deleted/inactivated**?

Customized theme appearance "old_sidebars_widgets_data"
New value   { "wp_inactive_widgets": [], "sidebar-1": [ "block-2", "block-3", "block-4" ], "sidebar-2": [ "block-5", "block-6" ], "sidebar-3": [] }
Old value   []

Many thanks, Olivia

I compared this code with the one when the widget was created and the two codes looked different, so I assumed that this code meant that someone deleted the widget.